# Objective-C Storing Information

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

In an iPhone app, the User can create Items - each Item needs to have a CGPoint, NSString and a few integers with information about it. The User can keep adding these Items.

How can I store all these variables for each of the Items and programmatically keep adding them to a list or array or something?

I tried using a **struct array** but it can't hold a NSString. I tried using a NSMutableAray of a custom class, but I can only add them if I make and name them by hand.

Any suggestions, ideas? Could I use a NSDictionary?

Comment: What do you mean by you "can only add them if you make and name them by hand"? An NSMutableArray sounds pretty perfect to me.

Comment: Second that. It sounds like the problem would be best solved by creating an Item class, which would store all the information about the item, and then storing each of those Item objects in a single NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `Item` class, that contains your `CGPoint`, `NSString`, and any other piece of info you want. Then, make an `NSMutableArray` and add new instances of your `Item` class as you see fit. `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` aren't really what you're looking for.

Comment: THANKS, i just did more research on NSMutableArraay and figured everything out.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`, but you have to wrap your non-object values (`CGPoint`s and integers) in wrapper objects.  The integers can be wrapped in `NSNumber`s and the points can be wrapped in `NSValue`s.